# Как привязать Crontab к пользовательской сессии?

Tags: python, linux, crontab

У меня программка с графикой, хочу ее запучкать ее при загрзки устройства. Программа при загрузке включается но граику не выводит, я так думаю что она не понимет куда выводить изображение. Как мне заставить ее выводить GUI на экран. Из консоли программа запускается идеально. Заранее спасибо

Comment: А как именно в вашем линуксе настроена графика? Куда именно нужно выводить изображение?

Answer (score 1):

Таймер systemd как замена крону будет работать на десктопных системах которые используют logind

Создай сервис `/home/sasha/.config/systemd/user/prog.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Run prog

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/sasha/projects/prog
```

И таймер `/home/sasha/.config/systemd/user/prog.timer`

```
[Unit]
Description=Run prog every 10min

[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=10min
```

И включить этот таймер

```
systemctl --user enable prog.timer
```